# Como criar um array através de outro?

Tags: java, array

Tenho um problema que trata de fornecer um array ao programa e este deve devolver apenas os números ímpares desse array, sendo que para isso eu crio um array novo que receba os valores:

```
public void maiorValorImpar(int[] a) {
    int b= a.length-1;
    int[] arr2= {};
    int i=0;
    while(i<b) {
        if(a[i]%2 != 0) {
            arr2[i]= a[i];
            System.out.println(arr2);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Contudo com meu código atual, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
>   Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado, mas crie o hábito de dar nomes que realmente indicam o que cada coisa faz. `maiorValorImpar`, por exemplo, pode confundir outra pessoa (ou até vc mesma), já que o código não está verificando o maior valor ímpar, e sim copiando todos os ímpares para outro array (algo como `copiarImpares` seria melhor, por exemplo). O mesmo vale para as variáveis: `impares` seria bem melhor que `arr2`, `numeros` seria melhor que `a`, etc. Pode parecer um detalhe bobo, mas nomes significativos podem ajudar inclusive no raciocínio quando vc está montando a lógica...

Comment: verdade, muito obrigada, vou levar seu conselho em consideração! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro se deve a tentativa de acessar o primeiro elemento (`Index 0`) da `arr2`, sendo que `arr2` não possui nenhum elemento (`length 0`) pois você declarou ela com `int[] arr2= {}`, sem nenhum elemento entre as chaves.

No loop você está declarando `b` como `a.length-1`, o que faz com que o loop nunca verifique o último elemento de `a`, pois ele está no índice `a-length-1`, e a condição é `i < b`, por exemplo:

```java
a.length: 5;
b: a.length-1 = 4;
while (i < b); // o while só passará pelas posições 0, 1, 2 e 3, pois são menores que b (4)
```

Outra coisa que notei foi que você atribui `arr2[i] = a[i]`, deixando espaços vazios caso haja números pares antes de um ímpar, pois arr2 será atribuído na posição `i`, por exemplo:

```java
// Usando o seu código, porém assumindo que arr2 possui um tamanho suficiente
a:    [0, 4, 2, 87, 6, 9, 3]
arr2: [ ,  ,  , 87,  , 9, 3]
```

Para corrigir isso, utilize uma variável que guarda o índice atual de `arr2`:

```java
public static void maiorValorImpar(int[] a) {
    int b = a.length; // Correção da não verificação do último elemento
    int[] arr2 = new int[b];
    int i = 0, j = 0; // j guarda onde será colocado o próximo número em arr2
    while(i < b) {
        if(a[i]%2 != 0) {
            arr2[j]= a[i];
            System.out.println(arr2[j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Quando trabalhar com arrays que você não sabe inicialmente o tamanho, recomendo utilizar o ArrayList ([documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) ([w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp)), assim você não precisa alocar espaços na array que talvez não utilize, como na linha 3 do meu exemplo (`int[] arr2 = new int[b];`).

Comment: Muito obrigada! Tenho apenas uma questão, quando você define o `int[] arr2 = new int [b]`, porquê que você usa a variábel b e não dá erro?

Comment: De nada! Quando você declara um vetor com o seu tamanho, ele espera que o tamanho seja um número inteiro, por exemplo `int[] ex = new int[4]`. 4 é esse inteiro. `b` é um inteiro também, que nesse caso possui o valor de `a.length`, por isso é aceito. Poder declarar arrays assim é útil para quando você quer que a array tenha um tamanho baseado no resultado de outra parte do código.

Comment: Outra forma de pensar seria `int variavel = 4`, `int[] ex = new int[variavel]`: "Quero que o tamanho da array `ex` seja 4" ou "Quero que o tamanho da array `ex` seja **o valor contido** em *variável*"

Comment: Certo. Me deu uma grande ajuda msm, muito obrigada :)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays em java não podem crescer dinamicamente, depois que você define seu comprimento esse não pode ser mais alterado. Quando você faz `int[] arr2= {};` você está dizendo ao compilador para criar a array `arr2` com o comprimento 0.

Para solucionar você pode usar uma lista `List<int>` e o método `ArrayList.toArray( T[] a )` para obter o array.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int[] a = { 1, 3, 5 };
    int b = a.length;
    // cria uma lista de int
    List<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < b) {
        if (a[i] % 2 != 0) {
            // Adiciona a[i] a lista arr2
            arr2.add(a[i]);
            // Imprime o item i da lsta arr2
            System.out.println( arr2.get(arr2.size() - 1) ); // Leia os comentários               
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(arr2);
}
```

Comment: Em Java não dá pra fazer `List<int>`, tem que ser `List<Integer>`. Mas isso gera outro problema, pois se tentar converter `List<Integer>` para `int[]` usando `toArray` o código [não compila](https://ideone.com/FhvHcE), e a solução [não é tão direta assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41520842). Outra coisa, ao fazer `b = a.length - 1` você está ignorando o último elemento do array `a`, [veja](https://ideone.com/ICvYvb). E a linha que imprime o item pode dar erro tb, [veja](https://ideone.com/4I0uJ5)

Comment: @hkotsubo: Deu erro aqui 'int b = a.length - 1;' tem que ser `int b = a.length;` ou então manter   'int b = a.length - 1;' e fazer`while (i <= b)`.

Comment: Feita a edição. Falha grosseira a minha em subestimar o problema e fazer de cabeça.

Comment: Ainda pode dar problema na linha que imprime o item (dentro do `if`): https://ideone.com/7i4xBM - você deveria imprimir `a[i]`, não `arr2.get(i)`, já que `arr2` não necessariamente terá o mesmo tamanho de `a`, então os índices deles não estarão sincronizados...

Comment: Precisa de um contador paralelo.

Comment: Ou usa `arr2.get(arr2.size() - 1)`. Ou simplesmente imprime `a[i]` mesmo.

Comment: @hkotsubo Se imprimir `a[i]`  perde o foco da pergunta.

Comment: Agora `arr2.get(arr2.size() - 1)` é a melhor solução.

Comment: Se imprimir `a[i]` dentro do `if`, não vejo problema, já que é o elemento que acabou de ser adicionado em `arr2`